# How do I change the character set of an excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, character-encoding

I have an excel file that I need to change to UTF-16. is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current versions of Excel, you can do a File > Save As to save as a UTF-16 encoded tab-delimited text file, which will give you the character set you want but eliminate formatting, formulas, and other special Excel-y features. A regular Excel file should be able to display UTF-16 characters inside it. If you or one of the viewers of your file is having issues, it might have to do something with missing installed language packs.